# Date filtering with Django -- how to send start and end dates to my view?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to add date filtering to an event listing I have on my Django site. In other words, I want the user to be able to select start and end dates and then show all events on or between those dates.

I've tried the below code, which I feel like should be working.

relevant HTML

```
<div id="datefilter-container">
  <p class="js-command">Filter shows by date &#8595;</p>
  <div id="datefilter">
    <form name="date-range-form" id="date-range-form"
          action="{% url 'concerts:date_filter' %}" method="GET">
      <label for="start">Start date:</label>
      <input type="date" id="start" name="start">
      <label for="end">End date:</label>
      <input type="date" id="end" name="end">
      <button type="button" name="date_filter">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

urls.py (relevant line)

```
url(r'^date_filter/$', views.filter_by_date, name="date_filter"),
```

views.py (relevant function)

```
def filter_by_date(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        start_date = request.GET.get('start')
        end_date = request.GET.get('end')
        try:
            results = Concert.objects.filter(
                Q(date__gte=start_date) & Q(date__lte=end_date)
            )
        except Concert.DoesNotExist:
            results = None
        template = "concerts/calendar.html"
        context = {
            "results" : results,
            "start_date" : start_date,
            "end_date" : end_date
        }
        return render(request, template, context)
    else:
        return render(request, "concerts/calendar.html", {})
```

Nothing is happening when I press the submit button in my HTML. I'm not sure if this is a problem with my HTML or my view. A little guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should specify that the button should submit, so `<button type="submit">`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Nothing is happening when I press the submit button in my HTML.

That is because you did not specify that the browser should submit the query when you click on it. You can specify that by setting the `type=...` to `"submit"`:

```
<form name="date-range-form" id="date-range-form" action="{% url 'concerts:date_filter' %}" method="GET">
  <!-- ... -->
  <button type="submit" name="date_filter">Submit</button>
</form>
```

There are basically [three button types](https://html.com/attributes/button-type/):

> **Button Types**
>
> There are three types of buttons:
>
> - **`submit`** — **Submits the current form data**. (This is default.)
> - `reset` — Resets data in the current form.
> - **`button`** — **Just a button**. Its effects must be controlled by something else (that is, with JavaScript).

Comment: Thanks, that got me to a screen, but I'm not getting any query results. Do you happen to see a problem with my view? I know there are some differences to filtering by dates than other data types.

Comment: @Danny: does the date format that you retrieve matches the date format in your `settings.py`?

Comment: @Danny: how do you render the responses (what do you do in the template of the results)?

Comment: This is my datefmt from settings.py: `'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"`. The user data is submitted in Y-m-d format, and probably doesn't include a time. So I think you've identified the problem – now to figure out how to tackle it. :)

Comment: @Danny: that is for logging, for input parsing, you should look at `DATE_INPUT_FORMAT`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-input-formats

Comment: And your second follow-up question helped me realize my context had a different name than in my template – problem solved. Thanks a ton!